# How to take Projects?

Tags: projects

please tell me how to take projects of any kind such as C,C++,JAVA, Web-Development. Please tell me authentic sources. Can anyone help me in this regard.

Comment: What do you mean by "take" projects?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm going for my first "reversal" badge here...
I'll go out on a limb and assume that you want to get work coding in C, C++, Java, etc..  You should find plenty of work on RentACoder http://www.rentacoder.com/RentACoder/DotNet/default.aspx.  There you can find projects that are in your area of expertise, bid on them, get work, deliver results, and get paid.

You will need to improve your communication skills!  I understand that English is not always everyone's first or favorite language. But to be in this business (and particularly freelance programming), you need to be very clear on what you are proposing to deliver.  You need to find that perfect balance between customer delight and making lots of money. You can't do that with poor communication skills, no matter how good your programming skills are.

I wish you luck.